# How can I cut a long image into smaller images so that each image file size is below some threshold (e.g., 2 MiB)?

Tags: image-processing, file-size

I have an image with a `1920x16883px` resolution: I'd like to cut it into images of `1920xYpx` resolution, with `Y` being the largest integers possible so that each image file size is below some threshold (e.g., 2 MiB). How can I achieve that? I don't want to manually cut it myself.

Comment: These quantities don't relate. Pixel dimensions and filesize (in a lossy-compressed file) can't be related through some function like you want.

Comment: @osullic thanks, yes, that's partly what makes the question more difficult.

Comment: Roughly, if you single image file is X MB, cutting the image in N pieces and encoding them with the same format and parameters will yield an equivalent total file size(with some margin due to format overheads). Soif you image is 10MB and you want subimages under 1MB, cut it into 10 parts.

Comment: @xenoid mostly agreed, but how to cut?

Comment: `Images#=Single image/Max size` and `Ypx= 16883/Image#`, with the caveat about headers (so take some margin) and you may have to check the last value if `Image#` isn't a divisor of `Ypx`.

Comment: For practical cutting, see [ImageMagick `-crop` operator](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/). In particular: "*As of IM v6.5.8-9 you can now add the special '@' flag to the "-crop" argument. This flag tells the "-crop" operator to try its best to equally divide the image into the number of tiles given*"

Comment: @xenoid thanks, some part of the image may be less compressible than others, so sometimesYpx= 16883/Image# will result in larger sizes than intended

Comment: Yes, but there is no practical way to determine in advance exactly how much something will compress. So take some margin and cut by image#+2 or else.  Or make a first guess and if parts are too big erase and start over with more parts.

Comment: I think the last 2 comments are the key comments - you can't do this in a 100% dependable way. This doesn't even really sound like a "normal" photography problem - which is what this site is intended for, not obscure data transfer issues.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like (with imagemagick):

```
convert image.jpg -crop 100x10% +repage image_%d.jpg
```

This will crop the image on size of 1920x1688 pixels. As is already explained this is lossy format so you can't be sure about the size in megabytes. You can play with percentage to make it closer to desired size.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say why you want to cut up the image. Sometimes the why is as important as the how. For example, if the why is that you have a limitation on file size (perhaps for emailing), then the solution is not to cut up your image, but to split the file. There are many solutions to doing that, but on a Windows machine, [WinZip will do a nice job of it](https://kb.winzip.com/help/winzip/help_splitdlg.htm). This approach has the major advantage that it makes reassembly of the image file easy and you are guaranteed the identical file you started with which isn't necessarity the case of splitting jpegs. There are similar utilities on other computer platforms.

Comment: This is a Windows-based version of [Jan Steinman's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/129927/35640) and seems perfectly reasonable, given we don't know why the OP wants to slice up his image.

Comment: @FreeMan, the idea of answer you mention is very low quality. Writing so many lines instead of one command is waste of time and effort. Moreover the answer assume usage of specific OS, which IMHO make it even lower quality.

Comment: Between these two answers, @RomeoNinov, we have options for 2 different OSs. Also, since the only _specific_ requirement was 2MiB, both of these answers will specifically meet that requirement. As was pointed out in your answer, image contents and compression algorithms will make it an iterative process to get all the slices down to 2MiB, making these even more efficient options than manually adjusting the ImageMagik command line multiple times until the criteria have been met. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan, if you check the question you will see "that each image file size is below some threshold (e.g., 2 MiB)" so the OP want on the output images. And want to be <2MB w/o mentioning how much.

Comment: Granted. These two answers will guarantee that on the first pass. Other tools may make multiple passes to ensure all pieces are <= `x` MiB. Nice thing about this Q&A format - multiple options can be given and the OP (or other future readers) can choose the one that works best for him.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I debated whether to make the answer a comment. The focus on file size argue against an esthetic consideration. Thus the suggestion to split the file rather than cut up the file. I provided an example for Windows, but note that options exist for other operating systems.

Comment: @EricS, keep it as answer. It is detailed enough and provide a way to "split" files relatively easy :)

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to manually cut it myself.

Does this mean you are unwilling to use command-line programs? What OS are you using?

If Linux or MacOS, the UNIX program `dd`, inside a very simple shell command that iterates over your file, will split it into pieces that can easily re-create the original. (Note that, if you split it into pieces that are JPEG images, you **cannot** recreate the original!)

This is from memory and `man` pages, and will undoubtedly need debugging.

```
#/bin/bash
segment = 0
while dd if=$1 bs=2M count=1 seek=$segment of=${1}-$segment
do
    segment += 1
done
```

1. Put this text into a file named `cutup`.
2. Make sure the file has execute privilege (`chmod u+x cutup`).
3. Execute the script with the image you want chopped into pieces (`./cutup myfile.jpg`)
4. It will create files named `myfile.jpg-0`, `myfile.jpg-1`, etc., until the original file is completely chopped up.

How does it work?

1. The first line tells the UNIX kernel to send the rest of the lines to the `bash` command. Find out more than you ever wanted to know about bash by typing `man bash`.
2. `segment` is a variable that will keep track of the file segment you are working on. Initialize it to zero.
3. `while` executes a command, followed by other commands, until the first command fails.
4. `do` and `done` set apart the commands that are executed in between doing the one right after `while`.
5. Each time through the loop, increment the `segment` that you are working on.
6. When the file is completely consumed, the `dd` command will return a non-zero result, which will cause `while` to break the loop, and the script will terminate.

Of course, all the real work happens with the `dd` command:

- Type `man dd` to find out more than you ever wanted to know about the `dd` command!
- `if=$1` set the input file to the argument to the shell scrip command, or `myfile.jpg` in our example.
- `bs=2M` set the block size to two megabytes.
- `count=1` set the number of blocks to write to just one.
- `seek=$segment` move forward `$segment` number of blocks into the file before writing a block to the output file.
- `of=${1}-$segment` write the 2 megabytes block of data beginning at $segment blocks into the file into the a file with the same name, with a dash and the segment number appended to the name.

(Note that, after splitting, none of these files will be useful JPEG images, so it is best to put the segment number after the ".jpg" extension, so no one will try viewing them as a JPEG file.)

It is left as an exercise to the reader how to use `dd` to re-assemble the file. :-}

Comment: Thanks, would the myfile.jpg-* files still be valid images?

Comment: The result files are not images...

Comment: If you want each file to be an image, I recommend GraphicConverter 11. It is a scriptable GUI-based image editor that you may be able to coax into cutting up a file into segments that are valid images. But it is very nerdly, and will take some work! https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/

Comment: The ImageMagick suite of command-line tools can probably do what you want. You don't identify your OS, but ```magick``` and friends are open-source, portable, and widely available. On MacOS, you can install them using homebrew (https://brew.sh), a package manager that can install many useful things. In looking at the man page, it looks like ```mogrify --extract``` could do what you want.

Comment: instead of `dd` just use `split`

Comment: Nice! Be sure to use the ```-b``` option, as it appears split's default behaviour is text-oriented. But it still doesn't do what the OP wanted, which I think ImageMagick *can* do.

Comment: Eric S just provided a [Windows-based version of this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/129930/35640). Given that we don't know why the OP wants 2MB chunks, both seem perfectly reasonable.